# What is causing the sort Function serializable in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting task not serializable for below code. 
However if I pass the function directly I don't get any error.

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass[T, SortOrder](implicit ord: Ordering[SortOrder]) {
  def getSorterFunc(): (T) => SortOrder
  def sort(rdd: RDD[List[T]]) = {
    val sortFunc = getSorterFunc()
    rdd.map(x => x.sortBy(sortFunc))
  }
}

object SampleObject extends MyAbstractClass[(String, Int, List[Int]), (String, Int)] {
  def getSorterFunc() = {
    case (username, id, addresses) => (username, id)
  }
}

val data = Array(("user1",1,List(12,211)),("u2",1,List(12,211)),("u1",2,List(12,211))).toList
val dataList = Array(data,data)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(dataList)
// This is working fine 
rdd.map(x => x.sortBy{ case (username, id, addresses) => (username, id) }) 
// This is giving task not serializable error.
SampleObject.sort(rdd)
rdd.collect
```

Error:

```
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
```

what is causing the error?

Comment: If you make `MyAbstractClass` extend `Serializable` - it works, so apparently your `SampleObject` is being serialized, but I can't see why...

Comment: I suspect on impilicit ord . since functions are serializable I am not sure why is this causing trouble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit here is the `implicit ord: Ordering[SortOrder]` - since the `sort` method (called within an anonymous function that must be serialized by Spark) implicitly takes `ord` as argument, the encapsulating object `SampleObject` must be serializable.

This is why using the local variable `sortFunc` isn't enough - indeed this relieves Spark of the need to serialize the object on which `getSorterFunc` is called, but there's still `ord` to take care of.

As mentioned in comments, you can fix it by making `SampleObject` (or `MyAbstractClass`) extend `Seriablizable`.

Another option would be to move the implicit parameter from the *class* (which makes it a member, which means it "carries" the class along with it when serialized) to the *method*:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass[T, SortOrder] {

  def getSorterFunc(): (T) => SortOrder

  def sort(rdd: RDD[List[T]])(implicit ord: Ordering[SortOrder]): RDD[List[T]] = {
    val sortFunc = getSorterFunc()
    rdd.map(x => x.sortBy(sortFunc))
  }
}
```

This works without having to serialize the class.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a pretty simple solution (based on Tzach Zohar's findings):

```
...
def sort(rdd: RDD[List[T]]) = {
  val sortFunc = getSorterFunc()
  val ordLocal = ord
  rdd.map(x => x.sortBy(sortFunc)(ordLocal))
}
```

Comment: nice. I had the local var but dint curry it on sortBy.